# System.Environment.Newline intermittently not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have some code that sends an email.

The code is generally along the lines of :

```
Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Field1:" + Field1.Text);
sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
.
.
.
```

The string is built, then converted to a string and passed to a function that sends the email.

This works for *most* of the fields in the form. However, there are a couple of fields that **never** get a line break. It's really weird that the same code is behaving differently.

I've read there are numerous ways to add a newline in a stringBuilder, and I've also tried

```
sb.AppendLine()
```

But that didn't work either.

Suggestions?

Comment: Format it as HTML and use a `<br/>` tag

Comment: IS this a problem with the text in your email or could it be your mail client? Perhaps take a look at the raw email data to confirm. Also HTML or plaintext email?

Comment: email body is html or text?

Comment: @Liam That's a workaround, assuming the recipient's client supports HTML messages, but it doesn't explain why the OP is having the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Tim Is there a pattern that you can discern? Is it random fields not getting the newline or the same field every time? Do the fields that don't get a new line contain any special characters?

Comment: @Chris - you were right. After tearing my hair out I noticed Outlook had an alert (which I didn't see before) that extra line breaks were stripped. When I clicked on the bar, the email renders properly. If you want to post an answer since it pointed me in the right direction, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Tim: Answer provided. I've come across that one myself which is why the answer so easily sprang to mind. Its one of the many things that has taught me to check output without using any kind of client if I can possibly avoid it. Simple text reader or hex editor or similar are always preferred. ;-)

Comment: Using a host specific linebreak for data that's sent over a network sounds like a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various mail clients will try to mess around with emails to try to make them look more like they think you want them to.

One common example is that sometimes plain text emails are artificially line broken in the sending process after a certain number of characters and a mail client might try to detect this and strip out those artificial line breaks. Most often it will do this by thinking that a single line break is a "fake" and that a double line break represents a new paragraph and should be preserved.

The best way around this is to send mail as HTML. Mail clients may have settings to turn off this undesired behaviour but there is no way to disable it in the mail itself as far as I am aware.

Comment: Good to know...unfortunately this application uses one email function to send from several places, and converting to HTML formatted mail would require a lot of updated code. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML line break tag. Make sure the email is set to allow HTML.

```
Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Field1:" + Field1.Text);
sb.AppendLine("<br />"); //use AppendLine so that source looks pretty. Use HTML break so that the rendered text has a new line


public static void SendMail(MailMessage mail)
    {
    mail.IsBodyHtml=true;
    //send the email
    }
```

Comment: Of course its worth noting that this may require other formatting put in since an HTML email will generally display very differently from a plain text one (eg collapsing whitespace).